# php file smaller than MAX_FILE_SIZE fails to upload

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an excel file through a form. The code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000"/>'
<input type="hidden" name="Cancel" value="N" />'
```

the file fails with error 2 - the file size is 225280 bytes

MAX_FILE_SIZE is set in the form, in php.ini and .htaccess. a phpinfo shows:

```
_POST["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]  20000000
upload_max_filesize 40M 2000000 (local/master)
http header: Content-Length 226781
```

post_max_size = 8M

and:

```
_FILES["datafile"]
Array
(
    [name] => CANAL36.xls
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 2
    [size] => 0
)
```

OS is a centos 5.3 with PHP Version 5.2.11 - I know this is old, but some dependencies prevent from upgrading.

Why, while I am well within the limits, this fails ?

thanks

Comment: sorry, exact html code is:<input type="file" name="datafile" size="60"><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000"/>

Comment: error=2 -> exceeds max_file_size in form: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Also note that `The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the file input field`. You have them the wrong way around, at least in your comment.

Comment: You're a star !!! that was it !!! many thanks....